# Why does the following snippet always returns a Double

Tags: java

Why does the following snippet always returns a `Double`, even if `integer` is true?

```
double bar = 100.0;
Object foo = integer ? (int) bar : bar;
```

The same code, rewritten as:

```
double bar = 100.0;
Object foo;

if (integer) {
    foo = (int) bar;
}
else {
    foo = bar;
}
```

works without any problem.

Comment: Because `integer` is `false`

Comment: I suggest including all relevant code (including initialization of "integer").

Comment: Foo being an Object, wouldn't it be wise to cast via (Integer) instead of (int) ?

Comment: Also, don't use an alternate case version of a reserved keyword as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertion of the equivalence of the ternary-based and conditional-based code is wrong.

This code:

```
integer ? (int) bar : bar;
```

has to return a single type, and that is `double`, since `bar` is a double, and `(int) bar` can be promoted to a double.

As such in

```
Object foo = integer ? (int) bar : bar;
```

the RHS is autoboxed to a `Double`.

```
void ternary(double bar, boolean integer) {
  Object foo = integer ? (int) bar : bar;
}
```

Decompiled:

```
  void ternary(double, boolean);
    Code:
       0: iload_3
       1: ifeq          10
       4: dload_1
       5: d2i
      // int promoted to double here.
       6: i2d
       7: goto          11
      10: dload_1
      // double autoboxed to Double here.
      11: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
      14: astore        4
      16: return
```

In the conditional form, there is no promotion from int to double: expression assigned to `foo` in the positive case is of type `int` (autoboxed to Integer), and in the negative case is of type `double` (autoboxed to Double):

```
void conditional(double bar, boolean integer) {
  Object foo;

  if (integer) {
        foo = (int) bar;
  }
  else {
        foo = bar;
  }
}

  void conditional(double, boolean);
    Code:
       0: iload_3
       1: ifeq          14
       4: dload_1
       5: d2i
       6: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       9: astore        4
      11: goto          20
      14: dload_1
      15: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
      18: astore        4
      20: return
```

Answer (score 0):

with the "? :" operator, each side of the ":" MUST return the same value type. So the compiler casts as it can ...

try this :

```
Object foo = integer ? (Object)new Integer((int) bar) : (Object)new Double(bar);
```